# How to use condition in geom_text / nudge_y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want text labels were above or under of bar cap depending on where is more space for them. Now it's always down which is not always looks good:

[image: example]

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

numa.nodes <- tibble (
  numa_name = c("numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_02","numa_02","numa_02","numa_02"),
  counter_name =c("cpu01","cpu02","cpu03","cpu04","memory_used","memory_total","cpu01","cpu02","memory_used","memory_total"),
  value = c(sample(0:100,4), sample(0:32,1), 32, sample(0:100,1), sample(0:100,1), sample(0:128,1), 128)
)

 numa.nodes <- numa.nodes %>% add_row(
   numa_name = c("numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_04","numa_04","numa_04","numa_04"),
   counter_name =c("cpu01","cpu02","cpu03","cpu04","memory_used","memory_total","cpu01","cpu02","memory_used","memory_total"),
   value = c(sample(0:100,4), sample(0:32,1), 32, sample(0:100,1), sample(0:100,1), sample(0:128,1), 128)
 )

 
 numa.nodes <- numa.nodes %>% add_row(
   numa_name = c("numa_05","numa_05","numa_05","numa_05","numa_05","numa_05","numa_05"),
   counter_name =c("cpu01","cpu02","cpu03","cpu04","cpu05","memory_used","memory_total"),
   value = c(sample(1:100,5), sample(1:64,1), 64)
 )
 
 
numa.nodes <- numa.nodes %>% mutate(counter_name=factor(counter_name,levels = unique(counter_name),ordered = T))

memory_columns <-  numa.nodes %>% filter(counter_name=='memory_total')
memory_y_scale <- max(memory_columns$value, na.rm = TRUE) + 6




plot_numa = function(num){
  
  df = numa.nodes %>% filter(str_detect(numa_name, num))
  
  cpu_plot = df %>%
    filter(str_detect(counter_name, "cpu")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = counter_name)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = 100), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_col(aes(y = value), fill = "#00AFBB", color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(y = value, label = paste0(value,"%")), nudge_y = 5, color = "black") +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "CPU", y = "")
  
  memory_plot = df %>%
    filter(str_detect(counter_name, "memory")) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = counter_name, values_from = value) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "") ) +
    geom_col(aes(y = memory_total), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_col(aes(y = memory_used), fill = "#FC4E07", color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(memory_total, "GB"), y = memory_total), nudge_y = 5, color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(memory_used, "GB"), y = memory_used), nudge_y = -3, color = "black") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylim(0, memory_y_scale) +
    labs(x = "Memory", y = "")
  
  ggpubr::ggarrange(cpu_plot, memory_plot, ncol = 2) %>% ggpubr::annotate_figure(top = paste("NUMA",num))
  
}

numa_numbers <- unique(numa.nodes$numa_name) %>% str_remove ("numa_")

ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = map(.x = numa_numbers, .f = ~plot_numa(num = .x)))
```

I tried to change this line:

```
 geom_text(aes(label = paste(memory_used, "GB"), y = memory_used), nudge_y = -3, color = "black")
```

to something like that:

```
     geom_text(aes(label = paste(memory_used, "GB"), y = memory_used),nudge_y =  ifelse( (memory_total-memory_used) > 10, 5, -3)
                                                                                , color = "black")
```

But I've got an error:

```
Error in ifelse((memory_total - memory_used) > 10, 5, -3) : 
  object 'memory_total' not found
```

1. Is there a better way to print labels optimal way?
2. What am I doing wrong?
3. How to change color of label to more contrast ie black on white, white on red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way:  The nudge value will be different (potentially) for every observation in your data frame.  That means that this is something that should be handled within `aes()`, where stuff is designed to change with your data, rather than `nudge_y`, which is designed to be a constant (and complains if used otherwise).

So, the solution is to do away entirely with `nudge_y` and build your `ifelse()` statement directly into `aes(y=...)`.

In this case, here's the replacement for that particular `geom_text()` line:

```
# to see the same plot posted here, put this at the top of your code
set.seed(7331)
...
# plot code...
...  +

geom_text(aes(
      label = paste(memory_used, "GB"),
      y = ifelse((memory_total-memory_used > 10), memory_used + 5, memory_used - 3)),
      color = "black") +
```

[image]